# Can I loop inside an PHP array like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, loops

Is possible to loop trough an array in php like we do it in JavaScript for example without using the `for ( $X  as $Y){}`

For example we in JavaScript we can use this code :

```
var names=['john','tom','jane'];

for (i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        names[i];
 }
```

Now in the case of using the same method for this loop it would be this one  and it gives us an error :

```
$names=['john','tom','jane'];
    for ($i=0;$i<$names.length;$i++){
        $names[$i];
    }
```

So is there a way around this?

Comment: [`sizeof()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)

Comment: `foreach` may also be a good option for you; it eliminates having to dereference the array.

Comment: @GregSchmidt  Yes i was only was not sure if this type of method would work on PHP like i does in javascript

Comment: Did you Google `PHP foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the code gives you errors because you have written lenght wrong. It should be sizeof() or count().Secondly there is also another option for looping through array. That’s **foreach**. As I’m not on the computer you could check out the php manual for foreach and how to use it. I hope I was useful !

Comment: You don't get the size of an array by writing `length` in PHP. `count()` or `sizeof()` are the methods for that.

Comment: Oops my bad, yes you are correct ! I updated my answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) for the length of the array.

```php
$names = ['john', 'tom', 'jane'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($names); $i++){
  echo $names[$i];
}
```